# Determine hyper-prior for gaussian distribution from existing data

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, conjugate-prior

Not sure how to **determine hyper-prior for prior distributions**, specifically **using historical data**. 
First what I am doing: I want to estimate parameters for a normal likelihood function using Bayesian approach so that I can use historical data as my priors. (which is exactly the advantage of Bayesian approach)

I have a normal likelihood function, determined by the nature of my research questions $P(data|\mu,\sigma)\sim Norm(\mu,\sigma)$ and want to estimate the distributions of $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Besides my own data, I also have a historical database from which I want to estimate the prior distribution. I know with a normal likelihood function, If I choose also a normal prior over $\mu\sim Norm(\mu|\mu0 ,\sigma0)$ I will get a close-formed solution (Murphy K. 2007). Then the question becomes: how do I estimate the hyper-priors ($\mu0$ and $\sigma0$) for the prior of $\mu$?

Secondly, I am not quite sure if my model is univariate or bivariate normal. By looking at my data and the historical data they do have different variance. For the bivariate case, I need to consider a normal-gamma prior to get a conjuguated distribution. Then the same problem applies here, how do I estimate hyper priors for the gamma distribution($\alpha , \beta)$?
I have no clue where to start from so If you know of any good reference I am much appreciated.

Comment: I think I have found solution to my first question regarding known variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found solution to my first question regarding known variance. In [Alber and Lee (2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5489251/pdf/nihms830262.pdf) they stated the "standard model by Gelman" is $\mu \sim N(\mu0, \sigma /n_{\mu})$, where $\mu0$ is mean of prior which is the empirical mean of the historical data in my case, $\sigma$ is the known variance, $n_{\mu}$ is the hypothetical size of prior. Since I have real historical data, $n_{\mu}$ can just be the sample size of the historical dataset.

In the same paper the authors also examined the case of unknown variance $\sigma$. However, I don't quite understand their statement about how to estimate the parameters (a and b) for the inverse gamma prior on  $\sigma$.

Comment: Update: the second question solved. Use a joint Normal Inverse Gamma distribution as the conjugate prior to normal likelihood function with unknown mu and sigma. Hyper priors are estimated based on prior data (or characteristics of hypothetical prior data).